# How to change data layout in SAS (possible PROC SQL)?

Tags: sql, sas

Using SAS (I'm thinking PROC SQL or PROC TRANSPOSE, but I'm also open to other methods): any tips on how to convert my data with the following data format:

```
ID CODE VALUE  
AA 1A   100  
AA 1A    10  
AA 2B   120  
AA 2C   210  
AA 3A   110  
BB 1A    20  
BB 3A   112
```

Into this format:

```
ID 1A  2B  2C  3A   
AA 110 120 210 110  
BB  20   .   . 112`
```

What I need to do is to create a table where the values of the "CODE" variable from my original table become table headers on my second table.

I was trying to use PROC TRANSPOSE but it wouldn't work due to my "BY" condition (variable "CODE") not being unique:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=table1 OUT=table2;
    BY ID;
    ID CODE;
    VAR VALUE;
PROC PRINT DATA=table2;
    TITLE 'Test of flipped data';
RUN;
```

Any feedback is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look up `proc transpose` documentation.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tried using PROC TRANSPOSE but not working since the variable in my BY condition is not necessarily unique.

Comment: ID=AA, CODE=1A, VALUE=10 and 100. How do you want to deal with that? Which value to choose?

Comment: Do you just have those 4 possible codes, or are there more (or an unspecified number)? 'Cause if there's a small amount, there's a pretty easy PROC SQL solution here. Otherwise, go with the combination SQL/Transpose code others have already supplied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the VALUE column before TRANSPOSE.  Many ways to do that, I show SQL here.

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table temp as
      select id, code, sum(value) as value
         from table1
         group by id, code
         order by id, code;
quit;

proc transpose data=temp out=table2;
    BY ID;
    ID CODE;
    VAR VALUE;
PROC PRINT DATA=table2;
    TITLE 'Test of flipped data';
RUN;
```

Comment: Happy to help.  If this answers your question, please mark it so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to sum the VALUEs together if IDs and CODE are the same. Such as when ID=AA and CODE=1A, you would want to have only one unique row with VALUE=110.

You can use `retain` in `DATA` step to compute the sum. `PROC SORT` with the `NODUPKEY` option to keep only the record with the highest value when duplicates between specified variables are detected.

```
data test2;
    set test;
    retain retainID retainCODE VALUE;
    if ID=retainID and CODE=retainCODE then SUM+VALUE; 
    else SUM=VALUE;
    retainID=ID;
    retainCODE=CODE;
    drop retainID retainCODE;
run;
proc sort data=test2;
    by ID CODE descending SUM;
run;    
proc sort data=test2 nodupkey;  *Use NODUPKEY to keep row with highest SUM;
    by ID CODE;                 *Checks for duplicates between ID and CODE;
run;
proc transpose data=test2 out=fat;
    by ID;
    ID CODE;
    var SUM;
run;
proc print data=fat noobs; run;
```

`proc transpose` is probably the easier way in this case to make a long data set into a fat one. http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/060-2009.pdf Otherwise, you'll have to use the data step which would be a pain.